# Unable to get Nodemcu 2.1.0 working on ESP8266 ES-12

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, firmware, flash-memory

I am trying to get the latest version of NodeMCU firmware working on my ESP8266 ES-12 module. I have followed the following steps with v1.5.4.x and it seems to be working just fine. Here are the steps:

1. Erase the flash `esptool.py --port /dev/cu.usbXXXX erase_flash`
2. Flash init data `esptool.py --port /dev/cu.usbXXXX write_flash -fm dio -fs 32m 0x3fc000 esp_iot_sdk_v2.1.0/bin/esp_init_data_default.bin`
3. Flash the actual build files `esptool.py --port /dev/cu.usbXXXX --baud 115200 write_flash -fm dio -fs 32m 0x00000 0x00000.bin 0x10000 0x10000.bin`

When I boot, I encounter the following after a file system format message

```
    Got answer! Communication with MCU established.
    AutoDetect firmware...

    Can't autodetect firmware, because proper answer not received (may be unknown firmware). 
    Please, reset module or continue.
    l��r��c�n�����p�|����x��ǒ��p
    �nn��;�n�����b�$rrp�n�������l���b�n��n���쎟
    �p��nn�����l`���#�n��{nr���;����rp�n����r���pp��<��
    ���p��nn���r��#�n�$�l`�8`rn|��n����l`9~����#�n�$���nn���l`nn����r��l�pp��<����b��<~�n����l`�n��Ìrnr���;����{r�ےn����l`�����x�n��>r���n�b��lrb�������l�|��n���l`�<r�x��l`#�r����8��� #�r����8���0��lrr��;l�Ğb����bp�b��l��p����l�x~�n�nܒ��r���l���l��������l�{�n��ܒ��b�l���8�b�>��ܒ��b�|�rr�
    Formatting file system. Please wait...

    ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

    wdt reset
    load 0x40100000, len 26772, room 16 
    tail 4
    chksum 0x93
    load 0x3ffe8000, len 2432, room 4 
    tail 12
    chksum 0x74
    ho 0 tail 12 room 4
    load 0x3ffe8980, len 136, room 12 
    tail 12
    chksum 0x67
    csum 0x67
    csum err
    ets_main.c rl��r��c�n�����p�|����x��ǒ��p�nn��;�n�����b�cl`$`nn�������l���b�n��n���쎟�p��nn�����l`���#�n��{nr���;��?��rp�n����r���pp��<�����p��nn���r��#�n�$�l`�8`rn|��n����l`;~����#�n�$���nn���l`nn����r��l�pp��<����b��>~�n����l`�n��Ìrnr���;����{r�ےn����l`�8���;�b�Ē`$��r���wn��bp�
```

Like I mentioned before, following the exact same steps for v1.5.4 worked absolutely fine and I get a proper lua prompt after the file system is formatted. What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you figure this out ? was it a version problem ?

Comment: @KevinRoy, I did figure it out. I reconnected the device and used a stable power source and it just worked one day. I stopped using NodeMCU though, got myself a WemosD1 Mini and am using the Arduino framework on it now. A lot more docs are available for it.

Comment: That did not help me. I think something really went wrong with my flash. I changed the device and its working as expected. I keep it at 3.4-3.5V